# Serve different servers based on CNAME for domain with apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, virtualhost

I've looked a bit around here on serverfault, but can't seem to find anything related to my issue (maybe because i don't know what to search for).

Anyways, my issue is that i have 2 servers. One main server for displaying my website and another for the email where we also check our emails etc. (currently just by entering the ip address)

I would like it so that the subdomain of "mail.domain.com" redirects to our mail server and "www.domain.com" redirects to the main server that displays the website. This is also the server that domain.com points to.

I've tried to edit the configuration files and added a vhost.conf file with the following code at the server "www.domain.com" is pointed to. Furthermore both servers are amazon linux ami.

```
   <VirtualHost domain.com:*>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"
    ServerName domain.com    
    ServerAlias www.domain.com

    <Directory "/var/www/html/">
        ServerSignature Off
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks IncludesNoExec
        AllowOverride All

        # Insert the following:
        Require all granted

    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

My question is then:

is it possible to serve another server? so that the additional configuration looks something like this...

```
   <VirtualHost mail.domain.com:*>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    DocumentRoot 128.02.12.12 #ipAddressOfOtherServer
    ServerName domain.com    
    ServerAlias mail.domain.com

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: No, that's now how it works.  You change DNS for `mail.domain.com` to point to the IP address of the other server.

Comment: Please note that each DNS name should occur only once in all ServerName /  ServerAlias directives when you do name based virtual hosting. Having two identical `ServerName domain.com` entries may have unexpected results

Comment: Also note that using your web server to display  (web) content hosted on a different server is usually called a "reverse proxy" and well documented.

Comment: The answers below are all, I think, wrong.  You can't have a single IP and 2 http services on boxes both on the same port. You cant redirect the traffic, but what you can do is proxy it (reverse proxy). Use s virtualhost container + mod_proxy in Apache.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can make the two www.domain.com & mail.domain.com work on a single IP address.
Step 1: Make sure the subdomain1.domain.com & subdomain2.domain.com points to your server IP.
Step 2: Add virtual host entry as per your requirement.

### CNAME Info :

The major advantage of using CNAME is that if we change the IP address of one A record then any CNAME record pointing to that host will also be changed.
The DNS resolves the system’s domain name to its IP address, but sometimes more than one domain name resolves to the same IP address, and this is where the CNAME is useful.
A machine can have an unlimited number of CNAME aliases, but a separate CNAME record must be in the database for each alias.

### Virtual host Info :

DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName subdomain1.domain.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName subdomain2.domain.com

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

Answer (score -1):

The short answer:

Never specify the same domain name in several VirtualHost blocks. It should be something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mail.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mail.domain.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

The fact mail.domain.com is CNAME domain.com is completely irrelevant for Apache. You configure it exactly as if it was direct A record, not CNAME.

The long answer:

You confused two different aspects of domain names.

CNAME is a term of DNS. It is the way to tell a requesting client to seek for another record for requested information, i.e. to create an alias of that DNS resource record. It is often used for A records, in which case you essentially have two names which point to same IP address. This will work exactly same as if you have an A record in place of CNAME.

Apache VirtualHost is an Apache term, and for name-based virtualhosts it corresponds to HTTP Host header. Apache (and any other web server) doesn't care how you resolved a host name to IP address. By the time you are sending to it a particular HTTP request, you are already connected to some IP address. The web server doesn't care at all how you get to know that IP address, was it taken from a DNS A record with that name, from a DNS CNAME which points to some other A record, or from local "hosts" file, or whatever.

For the web server the only place where it is ever considers IP address you connected to is if you set up an IP-based virtual hosting, then used server IP must match the IP address on which requested virtual host is set to answer. (I.e VirtualHost IP and either ServerName or some ServerAlias must both match for this VirtualHost to be selected to serve the request.)
If you use "*" in place of IP address in VirtualHost directive, it will not care for specific IP address at all. All it cares for is the host name you place into Host header of HTTP request. It selects a particular VirtualHost for which value of ServerName or ServerAlias is the same as in the Host header of the request.

On the other side, web browser doesn't care how the IP was resolved either. Was it obtained directly because the host name you used has an A record, or if it was CNAME of another A record, or even DNS wasn't used at all and that hostname was resolved using local "hosts" file - it doesn't matter. The system resolver returns some IP address for provided host name, and then web browser connects to that resolved address and puts the provided host name into request Host header.

So, the DNS organisation doesn't have anything to do with internals of web server configuration. You don't have to reflect it in the configuration. DNS is simply the way to know IP address of the server, and the server in general only uses host names and never considers how they are represented in the DNS.